# 'Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I run my webserver on windows (XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2). I am creating files and folders like this:

```
use File;

...

$Path = app_path()
       . '/Projects/'
       . strtolower($Project->name)
       . '/Schema/';

if (File::exists($Path)) {
    $result = 1;
} else {
    $result = File::makeDirectory($unitPath , '775', true);

    $content = "the content is basically a whole controller";

    $file   = $Path . strtolower($Unit->name) . '.php';
    $bytes_written = File::put($file, $content);

    if ($bytes_written === false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The file which I create is a `PHP` controller.

The files and folders are created. However by using `git bash` I noticed that the permission is not set to `775` even though I have specified it in `makeDirectory`, same for the files.

[image: git bash]
[image]

If I try to execute an action from the created file (which is a controller), then I get:

> ErrorException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 440:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied

How can I solve this, other than running my webserver on linux instead of windows?

*NOTE*: Everything works fine on my computer at home, where I also run the webserver on windows. The only difference is that I am using **Windows 10 64bit** at home and **Windows 7 64bit** here at work.

---

*UPDATE:*

The ErrorException  `include(C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium): failed to open stream: Permission denied` dissapeared after executing `composer update`. But the question how I can create a file/folders with specific permissions persists.

*UPDATE 2:*

After creating a new file the ErrorException appears again...

Comment: No clue if this is helpful, but I'm using the following `File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0777, true, true);` which works for me so you might give that a try. Note how it has an extra 0 and it's not a string but an integer. Might be worth a try :p

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this, but that made no difference.

Comment: Man your answer saved my ass. Running composer update DID INDEED HELP, I still have no idea how to fix this permanently, but at least a workaround. Thanks. You should post an answer to your question with this trick in it. It's not a solution, but at least it helps partly.